# Two Rio instances on same network - java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;

Tags: java, linux, rio

I have seen the following error reported in a few places, but not in the context I am getting it. So if anyone can give some advise, I would appreciate it.

> java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1;

I have two Rio (http://www.rio-project.org/docs/index.html) servers running on the same network. If I run them one at a time, they run with no problems, however if I try run them at the same time, I get the above error. So it looks like they are trying to share the same resource (port?).

For example:

```
./bin/startall
```

[image]

More info:

Server 1

```
[jboss@primary etc]$ cat hosts
xx.10.7.xx ws1.company.com
xxx.25.20.xxx CLapp.xxxx.co.za
xxx.216.xxx.7 api.xxxx.com
xx.199.180.xxx smtp.outlook365.com webmail.domainlocalhost.com smtp.domainlocalhost.com

xxx.28.xx.10 ota.tulx.co.za

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 primary primary.company.com
::1         primary.company.com localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 primary
xxx.101.60.xxx repo1.maven.org
xx.200.xxx.14 primary.company.com primary
```

Server 2

```
[jboss@uat etc]$ cat hosts
xx.10.7.13 ws1.company.com
xxx.25.20.xxx CLapp.xxxx.co.za
xxx.216.xxx.7 api.xxxx.com
xxx.199.180.xxx smtp.outlook365.com webmail.domainlocalhost.com smtp.domainlocalhost.com

xxx.28.65.xx ota.tulx.co.za

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 uat.company.com uat
::1         uat.company.com localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6  uat
xx.200.xxx.5 uat.company.com uat localhost
xxx.101.60.xxx repo1.maven.org
```

UPDATE

I tried removing 'localhost' where it's repeated twice on Server 2's hosts file for the two IP's, but I still get the error.

i.e. I changed:

```
xx.200.xxx.5 uat.company.com uat localhost
```

to:

```
xx.200.xxx.5 uat.company.com uat
```